# How to maintain state in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Basically, I have a list of products, in this list, I have a favorite function, but when I am logged out and favorite a product, it returns me to the login screen. After logging in, I have to do the favorite process again, I have to find a way when the user clicks on the favorite product when he returns from the login it is already filled in, I am using the `Redux toolkit` for the states

```js
const addRemoveWishlistItem = async (idProduct: string) => {
    if (!userLogged) return navigation.navigate('/login')

    const isServiceLoading =
      removeWishlistItemQuery.isLoading || addWishlistItemQuery.isLoading

    if (!idWishlist || isServiceLoading) return

    if (favoriteId.includes(idProduct)) {
      store.dispatch(UpdateLastFavoriteAdded(null))
      return removeWishlistItemQuery.mutate(idProduct)
    }

    store.dispatch(UpdateLastFavoriteAdded(idProduct))
    return addWishlistItemQuery.mutate(idProduct)
  }

  const handleDeleteAllFavorites = async () => {
    return removeAllWishlistItemsQuery.mutate()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily, you can store the actions with their related data in the `localStorage`, and after every login process, first of all, check the `localStorage` for the queued actions.